# What is the Rust equivalent for abstract classes?

Tags: rust, abstract

I am still a beginner in Rust and I am stuck on a point concerning the traits.
Despite many attempts, I can't find a code equivalent in rust for abstract classes.
Here is an example of Typescript code using them:

```
export interface NodeConstructor<T> {
  new (data: T): Node<T>;
}

export abstract class Node<T> {
  public data: T;
  public key: string;
  public parentKeys: string[];
  public childKeys: string[];
  public parents: Node<T>[];
  public children: Node<T>[];

  constructor(data: T) {
    this.data = data;
    this.key = this.buildNodeKey();
    this.parentKeys = this.buildParentKeys();
    this.childKeys = this.buildChildKeys();
    this.parents = [];
    this.children = [];
  }

  get hasParents(): boolean {
    return !!this.parents.length;
  }

  get hasChildren(): boolean {
    return !!this.children.length;
  }

  abstract buildNodeKey(): string;

  abstract buildChildKeys(): string[];

  abstract buildParentKeys(): string[];
}
```

Thanks to the 'mwlon' solutions in this post, I arrived at this result:

```
pub struct Node<T, BUILDER: ?Sized> where BUILDER: NodeBuilder {
    pub data: T,
    pub key: String,
    pub parent_keys: Box<[String]>,
    pub child_keys: Box<[String]>,
    pub parents: Option<Box<[T]>>,
    pub children: Option<Box<[T]>>,
    builder: BUILDER,
}

pub trait NodeBuilder {
    fn build_node_key(&self) -> String;
    fn build_parent_key(&self) -> Box<[String]>;
    fn build_child_key(&self) -> Box<[String]>;
}

impl<T , BUILDER> Node<T, BUILDER> where BUILDER: NodeBuilder {
    pub fn new(&self, data: T) -> Node<T, BUILDER> {
        Self{
            data: data,
            key: BUILDER::build_node_key(&self.builder),
            parent_keys: BUILDER::build_parent_key(&self.builder),
            child_keys: BUILDER::build_child_key(&self.builder),
            parents: None,
            children: None,
            builder: self.builder
        }
    }
    pub fn has_parents(&self) -> bool {
        match &self.parents {
            Some(_x) => true,
            None => false,
        }
    }
    pub fn has_children(&self) -> bool {
        match &self.children {
            Some(_x) => true,
            None => false,
        }
    }
}
```

Which implements like this:

```
struct TestModel {
    name: String,
    children: Option<Box<[String]>>,
    parents: Option<Box<[String]>>
}
impl node::Node<TestModel, dyn node::NodeBuilder> {
    fn build_child_key(data: TestModel) -> Box<[String]> {
        match data.children {
            Some(x) => x.clone(),
            None => Box::new([]),
        }
    }
    fn build_node_key(data: TestModel) -> String {
        data.name.clone()
    }
    fn build_parent_key(data: TestModel) -> Box<[String]> {
        match data.parents {
            Some(x) => x.clone(),
            None => Box::new([]),
        }
    }
}
```

But I still have one error I can't get over:

```
cannot move out of `self.builder` which is behind a shared reference

move occurs because `self.builder` has type `BUILDER`, which does not implement the `Copy` traitrustc(E0507)
node.rs(28, 22): move occurs because `self.builder` has type `BUILDER`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I can't implement 'Copy' on Builder since it is also a trait. Is there something I'm missing?
What are the best practices for such a structure in Rust?
I'm using rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)

Comment: There is no "equivalent for abstract classes" in Rust because Rust's type system is not built around inheritance and class hierarchies, but instead types and traits. It's a different paradigm, and that often means that you need to think differently about how you write your code. And while there may be ways of "forcing" such concepts into Rust, those will typically mean working against the principles the language is built upon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An abstract class couples together a piece of data which has the same shape for every instance of the type, and a set of behaviors which may differ between different instances of the type. This is a relatively unusual pattern in Rust, because Rust encourages decoupling of data and behavior more than other languages.

A more idiomatic translation of what you are trying to do would probably be along these lines. First, we make a type that holds the *data* representing a node:

```rust
pub struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    key: String,
    parent_keys: Box<[String]>,
    child_keys: Box<[String]>,
    parents: Option<Box<[T]>>,
    children: Option<Box<[T]>>,
}
```

We will need a way to create instances of this type, so we will give it a constructor. I do not know exactly how you intend `parents` and `children` fields to be filled, so I will leave them as `None` for now. However, if they are to be filled by reading data from an external source using `parent_keys` and `child_keys`, this constructor could be the right place to do that.

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn new(data: T, key: String, parent_keys: Box<[String]>, child_keys: Box<[String]>) -> Node<T> {
        Node { data, key, parent_keys, child_keys, parents: None, children: None }
    }
}
```

Next, we want a trait to abstract over possible *behaviors*. In your case, the behavior appears to be 'a way to create a node.' A trait should have exactly the methods necessary to implement its behavior, so:

```rust
pub trait NodeBuilder {
    fn build_node<T>(&self, data: T) -> Node<T>;
}
```

We can use generic parameters bounded by `NodeBuilder` in methods or structs to abstract over types that are *capable of* building a node. And we can define which types are capable of this by implementing `NodeBuilder` for them, like so:

```
struct TestModel {
    name: String,
    children: Option<Box<[String]>>,
    parents: Option<Box<[String]>>
}

impl NodeBuilder for TestModel {
    fn build_node<T>(&self, data: T) -> Node<T> {
        let parents = self.parents.clone().unwrap_or_else(Default::default);
        let children = self.children.clone().unwrap_or_else(Default::default);
        Node::new(data, self.name.clone(), parents, children)
    }
}
```

As you can see, this solution avoids coupling data and behavior when it is not necessary. It is, however, specific to the particular situation you have. A different abstract class might translate to a different set of types and traits. This is common when translating across programming paradigms: the role of one pattern in language A might be filled by several patterns in language B, or vice versa.

Instead of focusing too much on how to replicate a pattern like 'abstract classes' in Rust, you should ask yourself what problem that pattern was solving in TypeScript, and consider how to best solve *the same problem* in Rust, even if that means using different patterns.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly wish to replicate abstract classes in Rust, it is possible. You are on the right track with a trait representing the abstract methods (`NodeBuilder`) and a `struct` that is generic over that trait (`Node`). However, there are a couple issues with the example as written. First, your constructor.

- The `Node::new` method should not take `&self`, as it creates a new node, it does not initialize one that already exists. Unlike some other languages, Rust does not have constructors which operate on an existing object. Instead, object creation is expressed with free functions on a type, typically called `new`. Some other languages call these functions 'static.'
- In order to create a node, you will need a concrete instance of `BUILDER` to store in `self.builder`. This should probably be an argument to `Node::new`. Alternatively, you could make the methods on the `NodeBuilder` trait static and remove the `builder` field if you know that the builders themself will never carry state.

Taken together, this should lead to:

```rust
pub fn new(builder: BUILDER, data: T) -> Node<T, BUILDER> {
    Self {
        data: data,
        key: builder.build_node_key(),
        parent_keys: builder.build_parent_key(),
        child_keys: builder.build_child_key(),
        parents: None,
        children: None,
        builder: builder
    }
}
```

Second, implementing the class.

- All the 'abstract' methods of the type are encapsulated in the trait `NodeBuilder`. So rather than implementing additional associated functions on `node::Node<TestModel, dyn node::NodeBuilder>`, you want to implement `NodeBuilder` for `TestModel`:

```rust
impl NodeBuilder for TestModel {
    fn build_child_key(&self) -> Box<[String]> {
        match self.children {
            Some(x) => x.clone(),
            None => Box::new([]),
        }
    }
    fn build_node_key(&self) -> String {
        self.name.clone()
    }
    fn build_parent_key(&self) -> Box<[String]> {
        match self.parents {
            Some(x) => x.clone(),
            None => Box::new([]),
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, you can pass an instance of `TestModel` to `Node::new` (along with a piece of data) to create a `Node` whose abstract functionality is implemented by `TestModel`.